# How to delete the last cell in a column that contains data

Tags: vba, excel

This sounds like a very basic question (and it is), but I cannot figure it out and I cannot find a suitable solution on the web.

How do you select the last cell in a column that contains a numeric value and delete it?

I have formulas that go past this cell and return blank values in the column. This is what is tripping me up at the moment. My current code will go all the way down to where I have carried the formulas to and start deleting those cells instead of deleting the last cell with a numeric value.

My current code looks like this

```
Range("AA1500").End(xlUp).Select
With Selection.Delete
End With
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Thanks

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this explain to me what I did wrong in wording this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go down past cells with arbitrary strings in them and
delete the last numeric value (but not the last cell with a alphanumeric string in it), this should work:

```
Sub deleteLastNum()
  Dim row As Integer
  row = Range("A1000").End(xlUp).row
  For i = row To 1 Step -1:
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "A")) Then
       Cells(i, "A").Clear
       Range("A" & CStr(i + 1), "A" & CStr(row)).Cut Destination:=Range("A" & CStr(i))
       Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

It will also delete the last cell with a formula that evaluates to a number.  It moves down the range of cells in the column above it with characters in it to fill in the cleared cell.

Comment: This solution was simple and worked the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the total number of rows of a column (A) then check is last cell value is numeric or not, if numeric then clear that cell.

```
Sub del()
Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim k As Long
    Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1


    If IsNumeric(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k).Value) = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k).ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

This will check last cell for numeric value in column A.

Hope this is what you are asking.

**EDIT**

Implementing above for all the sheets in a workbook using a loop is like :

```
Sub del()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range


    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name)
    Dim k As Long
    Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1

    If IsNumeric(sh.Range("A" & k).Value) = True Then
    sh.Range("A" & k).ClearContents
    End If

    Next sh

End Sub
```

This will loop through each sheet like Sheet1, Sheet2 or whatever the name of the sheet may be and check for numeric value in last cell of col A, if found numeric then it will delete the value.

Comment: could you make this general instead of working on "sheet 1"? I want to loop this through several hundred sheets with different names

Answer (score 0):

You already got an answer to your post, just to be clear, the safest way to find the last row (let's say in Column "AA", according to your post), and ignoring blank cells in the middle, is by using the syntax below:

```
Sub FindlastRow()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

    ' rest of your coding here
End With

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 'SpecialCells()'

```
Sub ClearLastNumber(sh As WorkSheet, columnIndex As String)
    On Error GoTo ExitSub 'should 'columnIndex' column of 'sh' worksheet contain no numbers then the subsequent statement would throw an error
    With sh.Columns(columnIndex).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        With .Areas(.Areas.Count)
             .Cells(.Count).ClearContents
        End With
    End With
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

To be used in your "main" sub as follows

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ClearLastNumber Sh "A"
    Next
End Sub
```